# Another way to say "I didn't see you"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is there a way to imply I didn't see a person earlier using "saw" instead of "see" or "seen"?

edit:
I'd go with

> I never saw you

as suggested by Rathony in the comments. I would've upvoted/accepted it had he answered it rather commented. Thanks though. :)

Comment: Since you are being so specific that you want to use 'saw', I think you should make an attempt yourself to show us the kind of sentence you require. We can then comment. Otherwise you will simply get a lot of guesses (and probably arguments between contributors)

Comment: You can use "never" as it doesn't require a bare-infinitive after it as in "I never saw you". You need to edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: Before Anglophones got hooked on [*do-support*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support), you could have said ***I saw him not***. But there's a new generation of speakers who could probably say that today, since they're happy to sarcastically tack ***not*** on the end of any statement to assert that it's not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could say **"I never saw you there"** as mentioned in a comment,

or, if you are giving some explanation, **"I never even saw you there".**  which sounds more emphatic.

Answer (score 3):

"I saw no trace of you" or "I saw no sign of you"

Comment: Hi, just a heads-up. Your answer appeared in a "Low Quality Posts" link.

Comment: because it's short, shall I elaborate? :)

Comment: Why not. I don't see any problem with your answer, though.

Answer (score 2):

I will go with ***I saw no sight of you***.